# How to use Realtime Database and Firestore in the same Vue.js project

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I am attempting to build an Vue.js app that requires the use of both Realtime Database and Firestore for various functions across multiple components. So far, I have setup the `firebase.js` page to accommodate the components with Firestore functionality. However, Other components in the app have been set up to connect with Realtime Database in the same Firebase project, using lines of code such as `firebase.database().ref('.../')`. How can I set up the firebase.js file below to connect with both Realtime Database AND Firestore?

```
import firebase from 'firebase'

var config = {
  apiKey: '',
  authDomain: '',
  databaseURL: '',
  projectId: '',
  storageBucket: '',
  messagingSenderId: '',
  appId: ''
}

const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(config)

export default firebaseApp.firestore()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

voila, something like this might help, check [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase) for more

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
require('firebase/firestore')
require('firebase/database')

var config = {
  apiKey: '',
  authDomain: '',
  databaseURL: '',
  projectId: '',
  storageBucket: '',
  messagingSenderId: '',
  appId: ''
}

firebase.initializeApp(config)
export const database_realtime = firebase.database()
export const firestore = firebase.firestore()
```

Comment: This is close. I reconfigured the firebase.js file as you indicated, and then imported ```import { database_realtime } from '@/firebase``` into each of the Realtime Database components. However, I am getting the following error when I route to those components: ```database_realtime.database is not a function```

Comment: Don’t use .database... it’s already included on the variable... you can name database_realtime just ‘database’ if it makes more sense for you

Comment: thanks for answering this question last year. Would you be willing to take a look at another issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59952741/how-to-set-up-flexible-grid-in-vue-material